# how to change the md-menu background color fro:m CSS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, sass

i am using the angular materiel and i used the md-menu, but i want to change the background color of md-menu from a css file. is there a way to access the md-menu background from the css?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The .mdl-menu gets its color from the .mdl-menu__outline class.

Therefore adding this to your css will change the color

```
.mdl-menu__outline {
   background-color: <YOUR-COLOR>;
}
```

Also, note that a "[material-design-lite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/material-design-lite)" Tag also exists. Makes it faster and easier to get help.